# Use D3.js to find Centroid of SVG Path

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

This is a re-make of a question, because people didnt read the last one properly. I need the actual weighted centroid of a path. Not just a center, that is very important.

How do you use D3.js to find centroid of a region.

SVG Region code looks like this:

```
        <path id="JP" title="Japan" class="land" d="M852.76,362.01l0.36,1.15l-1.58,2.03l-1.15,-1.07l-1.44,0.78l-0.74,1.95l-1.83,-0.95l0.02,-1.58l1.55,-2l1.6,0.39l1.15,-1.42L852.76,362.01zM870.53,351.73l-1.06,2.78l0.49,1.73l-1.46,2.42l-3.58,1.6l-4.93,0.21l-3.99,3.84l-1.88,-1.29l-0.12,-2.52l-4.88,0.75l-3.32,1.59l-3.28,0.06l2.84,2.46l-1.87,5.61l-1.81,1.37l-1.36,-1.27l0.69,-2.96l-1.77,-0.96l-1.14,-2.28l2.65,-1.03l1.47,-2.11l2.82,-1.75l2.06,-2.33l5.58,-1.02l3,0.7l2.93,-6.17l1.87,1.67l4.11,-3.51l1.6,-1.38l1.76,-4.38l-0.48,-4.1l1.19,-2.33l2.98,-0.68l1.53,5.11l-0.08,2.94l-2.59,3.6L870.53,351.73zM878.76,325.8l1.97,0.83l1.98,-1.65l0.62,4.35l-4.16,1.05l-2.45,3.76l-4.41,-2.58l-1.52,4.12l-3.12,0.06l-0.39,-3.74l1.39,-2.94l3,-0.21l0.82,-5.38l0.83,-3.09l3.3,4.12L878.76,325.8z"/>
```

[image]

So how do i place a DOT/Icon etc. on the centroid on this, so that its on the  actual svg.

It needs to be CENTROID, so a fiddle example with a working example would make me very happy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is something in Geo API https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_centroid But won't be able to help you more than that.

Comment: ps, if your older question is still active, then it would better to edit it and close this one.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido i know that for next time, but someone didnt read the question properly, and marked it as a dublicate, with a link to a non-working answer. So its been inactive for quite some time now, as i guess people think its a dublicate, which it aint.

Comment: I also already know about the link you gave mate, but its not as easy as it looks to implement, which is why im seeking someone who can make a simple fiddle with this example path ive given.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316652/place-text-image-on-svg-path-centroid-using-d3) the question ? If so, it doesn't seem to be locked nor [to have been](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29316652/timeline)

Comment: And yes I also though it was kind of hard to implement this, and I'm not a great user of d3 so as I said, can't help you more than that…

Comment: @CodexDesign It was probably me who closed the question as a duplicate (although you seem to have deleted it now) -- if this was incorrect, then please nominate the question for reopening and comment instead of posting a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the centroid with a basic average calculation:

```
var centroid= {x:0,y:0};
var pointCount=0;
for( var i=0; i< parsedPath.length; i++ ){
    var point= parsedPath[i];

    if( point.relative == true){
        if( i > 0 ){
            point.x += +parsedPath[i-1].x;
            point.y += +parsedPath[i-1].y;
        }
    }
    if( point.x && point.y ){

        centroid.x += point.x;
        centroid.y += point.y;

        placePoint(point , "blue" , 0.2 );

        pointCount++
    }else{
        // close pathes -> ignored
    }

}
centroid.x /= pointCount;
centroid.y /= pointCount;
```

but, depending on your need, this may be not what you are loonking for. 
See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29994610/1064270) in a previous related question.

[The demo](http://codepen.io/gaelb/pen/qddyQo?editors=101)

Comment: Hi Gael, thats some pretty nice work, i see its a tiny bit outside, is it impossible in some path´s to have it inside the actual path?

Comment: I would also like it! Here, it is the centroid of the points, a solution may be to find the centroid of the shape. But the difficulties are to handle separated or nonconvex shapes.

Comment: Well your example is great to me, ill give it a bit more time if others come up with a better solution, if not, then ill find a way to work with yours. Thanks Gael

Comment: Hi Gael, im trying out your solution, but when i test on 1 path, it pulls the path our, and makes a huge version on top. How do i simply place the dot on the path where it is? example image: http://i.imgur.com/PvbSZv2.png

Comment: remove all the lines between `/*fit the map to the svg element*/` and `var centroid ...` :)

Comment: Awesome i tried that to, but had an error, at the circle.setAttribute down in the function, i removed that line to, and now it works. is that ok to do that?

Comment: is it also ok, those lines was used to center and scale the map. The line `circle.setAttribute`... was for apply the same transformation to the centroid.

Comment: Tried it out on a few regions of mine, it works on pretty much most regions, but some are really bad, like Japan etc. You have any idea´s to improve this? or do i need a completly other solution to make it work?

Comment: Thanks a lot Gael, i really appreciate this, i had a semi-hack idea, to offset up/down/left/right and checking if point was inside, but this aint a viable solution hehe, let me know if you need anything

Comment: I was trying to split the path by separate shapes, but it is still not very correct: http://codepen.io/gaelb/pen/pJjPpx?editors=101 so I search to split by convexes shapes, then place the centroid in the centroid of the centroid of all the shapes... is it clear??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77030/discussion-between-codex-design-and-gael).

Comment: I am still concerned by the problem, but I do not have yet some ready-to-use solutions